# Graph API "me/home", how to indicate whether user likes or not for a news item?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am listing a user's home page using the Graph API, simply retrieving and going over the results for "me/home". I would like to provide a Like or Unlike button, however I couldn't find a way to indicate whether or not the user previously liked the news item or not.

Is it possible to get the required information to know if the user previously liked the news items for all the results of "me/home" using the Graph API without issuing a separate request for each news item? If not, what would you do, resort to FQL or simply issue the additional requests?

Comment: AFAIK you can not like posts externally.

Comment: @CBroe POSTing to "`id`/likes" will result in the user liking the object associated with that id. DELETE to "`id`/likes" will result in unliking that object.

Comment: That is only for Open Graph objects, that is stuff that is hosted outside of facebook.com – the normal wall posts you get from `/me/home` can not be liked this way. The only way is the Like button plugin, from my tests it seems like you can set that to a Facebook post URL as well. As for the likes, you can ask for f.e. `me/home?fields=message,id,likes`, then you will get the like data for the posts as well. But I don’t know if pagination for the likes is on place there, so to find whether your current user is amongst the likers might require a high limit or paging.

Comment: Might be that you’ll be better of with using FQL instead – filter the stream table for the posts you’re interested in (there’s a filter key `nf` or something that should gives the same view as the user’s news feed), and then “join” the info whether your user likes those posts to it using multi queries.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, you should post an answer specifying there is no way to do what I desire and that my best bet is FQL so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out from my findings, there is no way to do this using the Graph API. In order to get that information, you would have to either `GET /[objectId]/likes` for each retrieved news item or use FQL.

I eventually ended up simply using FQL as CBroe suggested in a comment to my question.

Comment: does 'me/home' not return the array of 'likes'? In my case, there is an array of likes.

Comment: It contains just a portion of the likes that were made to the post, I am not certain if you can use this array to indicate whether the user likes the item or not (I did not find information about this at the time).